# Como insertar mas datos en una tabla? de forma parcial?Mysql

Tags: mysql, insert, datos

Como insertar mas datos en una tabla? de forma parcial,
es decir, quiero meter algunos datos y otros datos copairlos de otro empleado.

Codigo:

/*12. Añadir a la oficina de Londres otro empleado, Luis Valverde, con número de empleado 436, con los mismos datos que el empleado Alberto Soria pero su jefe será el director de la oficina de Madrid.*/

insert into Empleados (CodigoEmpleado,Nombre,Apellido1,Apellido2,Extension,Email,CodigoOficina,CodigoJefe,Puesto) values (null,"Luis","Valverde",436,"LONDON-UK",3) select  Email,Puesto where  Nombre = "Alberto";

Gracias de antemano!!!!!!![image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ok gracias de todos modos

Answer (score 0):

Creo entender tu pregunta pero a ver si entendi

QUIERES  INSERTAR LUIS  CON LOS DATOS DE ALBERTO?
PUES SERIA ALGO ASI

```
INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (CODIGOEMPLEADO, NOMBRE, APELLIDO1, APELLIDO2, ... ,EMAIL, CODIGOOFICINA, ...)
SELECT NULL, "LUIS", "VALVERDE", 236, "LONDON-UK", E.EMAIL, E.PUESTO FROM EMPLEADOS AS E WHERE E.NOMBRE = "ALBERTO";
```

Comment: He intentado poner eso, pero me sale error: value count at row 1

Comment: POR FAVOR VERIFICA SI TODOS LOS CAMPOS ESTÁN YO PARA AHORRARME ESCRITURA NO LO HICE PERO TU SI DEBES PONER TODOS, YA QUE ESE ERROR SALE CUANDO TUS COLUMNAS NO CORRESPONDEN A LAS COLUMNAS DEL INSERT A LAS SELECT

Comment: EN OTRA PALABRAS ESTO ```INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS (CodigoEmpleado,Nombre,Apellido1,Apellido2,Extension,Email,CodigoOficina,CodigoJefe,Puesto)
SELECT NULL, "LUIS", "VALVERDE", "SEGUNDOAPELLIDO", 236, E.EMAIL, "LONDON-UK", 3, E.PUESTO FROM EMPLEADOS AS E WHERE E.NOMBRE = "ALBERTO"; ```

Comment: Si me  di cuenta la abreviatura, y los puse todos pero me dcie que el CodigoEmpleado no puede ser nullo.       Error Code: 1048. Column 'CodigoEmpleado' cannot be null

Comment: PUEDES HACER QUE SE INCREMENTE ASIENDO QUE SEA AUTO INCREMENTAL ESE CAMPO  O  AGREGANDO UN ```( SELECT COUNT(*) +1  FROM EMPLEADOS)``` *CON LOS PARÉNTESIS*  EN VEZ DEL. **NULL**

Comment: O TAMBIEN PUEDES SOLO PONER ```(COUNT(*) +1)``` EN VEZ DEL **NULL**

Comment: INSERT INTO Empleados (CodigoEmpleado, Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2,Extension,Email , CodigoOficina,CodigoJefe,Puesto)
SELECT (COUNT(*) +1) "LUIS", "VALVERDE",null, 236, "LONDON-UK", e.Email, e.Puesto FROM Empleados AS e WHERE e.Nombre = "ALBERTO";   asi me asle error

Comment: Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: ```INSERT INTO Empleados (CodigoEmpleado, Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2,Extension,Email , CodigoOficina,CodigoJefe,Puesto) SELECT (COUNT(*) +1), "LUIS", "VALVERDE",null, 236, "LONDON-UK", e.Email, e.Puesto FROM Empleados AS e WHERE e.Nombre = "ALBERTO";```

TE FALTO LA COMA

Comment: Creo que dejo ese ejrcicio tio, te agradezco mucho pero es que voy insertando una cosa y me sale otra y no quiero marearte tampoco!!!Gracias de corazon!

Comment: intenta esto por ultimo  ```INSERT INTO Empleados (CodigoEmpleado, Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2,Extension,Email , CodigoOficina,CodigoJefe,Puesto) SELECT (COUNT(*) +1), "LUIS", "VALVERDE","", 236, "LONDON-UK", e.Email, e.Puesto FROM Empleados AS e WHERE e.Nombre like "%ALBERTO%" limit 1;```

Comment: solo te recuerdo que puedes poner lo que tienes actualmente en tu función? Al preguntar es importante siempre incluir lo que ya tienes hecho para que las personas te puedan ayudar, recuerda que este sitio no es para que la gente resuelva tareas o proyectos y hacer preguntas sin mostrar lo intentado normalmente termina en preguntas cerradas y/o con votos negativos –

Comment: Son Ejercicios para mejorar mi logica, los buscos en internet